# how to change the first part of each href and src url path?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a website in local (using xampp). Every css stylesheet and js script is linked with a relative path. When I load the website here on my pc with chrome or any other broser I don't have any problem to see it.

I'm trying to see also hot the website appears on my smartphone and I already finded the tutorials to make it possible: i configured a new port and each time I need to reach the website thorugh the smartphone I just need to write something like `192.168.1.7:80/andtherestogthepathtoreachthewebsite`

But I'm a problem: on smartphone the css stylesheets and js scripts are not loaded. And i discovered the reasons: because, for example, the css file style.css is loaded with this url `http://localhost/../../../style.css` while it should be `http://192.168.1.7:80/../../../style.css`: only in this way I could load on my smartphones all the files related to the website.

What I need is to change that first part of the url when the website is loaded through a mobile device. How can I do it?

Please, don't tell me "change the relative paths in absolute paths", I can't, the website is built with opencart, i can't change the relative paths.

Comment: Are you sure you're using relative path? From what you described, sounds like you're using absolute path instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use `<base>` tags, when you encounter these type of problems.

Syntax:

```
<base href='BASE_FOLDER_NAME'> // As per your question, BASE_FOLDER_NAME=andtherestogthepathtoreachthewebsite
```

So now you can link your CSS ans JS files without hassle,

```
<link href='css/style.css'>

<script src='js/script.js'></script>
```